# IE ignores anchor scroll padding ... sometimes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a one-page website that has some elements (company logo) with different id's which I use as anchors to navigate.
I've used CSS to add padding to these elements so that when I use my menu to scroll to them I don't get to see them attached (not sticky but no margin between window and element) to the top of my window.

```
#ontwerp, #project, #advies, #portfolio, #contact { /* 120px together, padding for anchor offset to screen, margin for filler */
margin-top: 90px;
padding-top: 30px;
}
```

When I view the site in Safari, Firefox and Chrome everything goes well.
When viewing in IE it all goes well for the first 2 (#ontwerp and #project) but if I use my menu to go to the other ones I get IE attaching them to the top of my screen.

I've tried adding @media\0 and setting the padding and margin as !important but to no avail.

Live site: http://www.vinck-interieur.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,
Here's the solutions to my own problem.

The problem eventually was that some of the elements in the elements marked with an ID had there position set to relative and some to absolute.
I set them all to relative and the issue was resolved

```
#ontwerp div, #project div, #advies div, #portfolio div, #contact div { 
    position: relative;
}
```